# What does ._Le means (Object Literal of a marker, google maps)

Tags: knockout.js, google-maps-markers

It's an marker object. Someone knows what does this _.Le means and how can I access the attributes if I push an object like this in an array ?

`_.Le {__gm: {…}, gm_accessors_: {…}, position: _.F, gm_bindings_: {…}, map: tg, …}`

Comment: What have you already tried out? It would be helpful if you could provide some more code and a more elaborated problem that you have...

Comment: The problem I had is solved but I am still curious about the ._Le thing. The above line of code is an object of a markers array. I added  a location attribute which stores the name of the location. But I was unable to access the .location attribute. Anyway, it's solved. Thanks for the reply